# Get the ID of each table row with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the lack of code but I just need someone to point the way and help me with an `each()` statement to alert each TR's ID.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  /* alert each TR's ID from #theTable */

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="theTable">
  <tr id="id1"></tr>
  <tr id="id2" class="theClass"></tr>
  <tr id="id3"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This type of question can find easily !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method and get `id` property of the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#theTable tr').each(function() {
    console.log(this.id)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="theTable">
  <tr id="id1"></tr>
  <tr id="id2" class="theClass"></tr>
  <tr id="id3"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I like this one, especially `this.id`. Weird that *attr* is still being used when *prop* has been around for ages (but neither is necessary). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

By using each for loop and add ids to array by push .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ids=[];
  $('#theTable tr').each(function() {
   ids.push(this.id)
  })
 alert(ids + '      Use your id');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="theTable">
  <tr id="id1"></tr>
  <tr id="id2" class="theClass"></tr>
  <tr id="id3"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
$("#theTable tr").each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you :)

```js
$(function() {

  $("#theTable tr").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('id')) // Here you go
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="theTable">
  <tr id="id1"></tr>
  <tr id="id2" class="theClass"></tr>
  <tr id="id3"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the different between your answer and answer given by Pranav C Balan ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#theTable").find("tr").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        });
    });
```

Hope this may help full

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {

  $("#theTable tr").each(function() {
     alert($(this).attr('id')); // Here you go
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="theTable">
  <tr id="id1"></tr>
  <tr id="id2" class="theClass"></tr>
  <tr id="id3"></tr>
</table>
```

Try Its Came In Alert

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code.

Both `.attr('id')` and `.prop('id')` can serve your purpose to get the id of `<tr>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* alert each TR's ID from #theTable */
  $("#theTable tr").each(function() {    
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    
    // prop() can also be used to get the id
    // console.log($(this).prop('id'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="theTable">
  <tr id="id1"></tr>
  <tr id="id2" class="theClass"></tr>
  <tr id="id3"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many jQuery solutions, for posterity this can be done in plain JS using *querySelectorAll* and *Array.prototype.forEach*:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#theTable tr'), x => console.log(x.id));
};
```

```html
<table id="theTable">
  <tr id="id1"></tr>
  <tr id="id2" class="theClass"></tr>
  <tr id="id3"></tr>
</table>
```